# Write a DFA to recognize the following language

Tags: math, theory, dfa, automata, nfa

The question is:

> Write a DFA to recognize the regular language *`L1` = `{w ={1,2,3} |` the sum of the digits in w is divisible by 5`}`*

More so, based on the input 1 , 2 , 3 the remainder of the sum should be 0 when dividing by 5. I am almost done this question but I can't seem to understand how to find the correct remainder when the input is 3. Since I have done most of the work I have a picture that I will link so you can understand where I am stuck.

[image: Picture]

```
Start State: q0
Accept State: q0
```

My problem is how to control the input 3 so the choices for it will lead to a remainder of 0 when dividing by 5.

Comment: You need to explain you diagram. What is the start state? Which are the accept states? I can find no interpretation of the diagram that works even for the language consisting just of 1.

Comment: Can you please share your idea, and name the states accordingly? To me, even the existing DFA seems wrong

Comment: Sorry, i edited and changed it. I'm not sure if the model is right for input 1,2 it looks right to me but not sure. Also I'm having trouble with the input 3.

Comment: @geforce: I dunno, if I pass `1111` I get into the accept state?

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll look into it when I get home and try to finish this.

Comment: Is this homework? Should we provide an explicit solution or would you prefer only hints?

Answer (score 2):

Here's some hints:

- Have one state for each possible remainder modulo 5.
- Given state x and character c, have the transition take you to state (x + c) modulo 5.
- Think about what your accept state would be given the meaning of your states.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think it needs more explanation :-)

Comment: You might want to draw them in a circle, that might make it look clean and easier to understand.